# How do I add columns and rows in a draw.io table?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

How do I insert new rows and columns in the Table in perspective to draw.io Mockup Text?

Comment: can you please tell me where to see "mock up" text ?

Comment: @USer345738380 : at bottom left, click on "More shapes..", then choose "Mockup"

Answer (score 66):

Assuming you're referring to the Table object in Mockup Text, when you go into edit mode (double click) select one of the rows. When you do that the table section will appear in the format panel on the right with the usual insert row/colum, before/after.

[image]

Comment: Also, if you select the whole table (instead of a single cell) then the grid button lets you change the dimensions of the whole table.

Comment: thanks David, do you know how to add gridlines to this table?

Comment: When I attempted to use the tables from "Mockup Text", it did not show these controls, and it was quite confusing.  I don't know if something has changed in the interim since this answer was posted.  Tables in the "Misc" category, on the other hand, did have the table controls in the format panel.

Comment: can you please tell me where to see "mock up" text ?

Answer (score 25):

[image: Table control appears]

Table controls appear when a particular cell is selected as shown in the screenshot. Works for all tables, whether from "Misc" or "Mockup" etc.

Method:

1. Single click selects the table
2. Double click selects all the text in the table
3. *Triple click* selects a particular cell contents, and then the table control appears on the panel

Comment: Triple click got the panel working for me. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for Bootstrap tables. Those don't seem to be editable, except for the cell contents.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using VSCode extension, you can find the table edit options under the Arrange tab.
[image]

Comment: Yep, that works! :) So not intuitive....that I had to search here :<

Comment: Also true of the full client.

Answer (score 6):

use search option in draw io to check for table
[image]

[image]

Then double click inside table's cell to get the table edit options at the right pane to add or delete row / column

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not specifically for tables, but Google led me to this question. You can copy then paste one of the children in UML objects, then add the child to the object by drag an drop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CTL-D while selecting a text box inside the container will create a duplicate of the entire row.