# How do I create basic tables with columns in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I want to create simple objects such as this:

```
+-------------+
|  Container  |
+-------------+
| col1 | col2 |
+-------------+
```

How can I accomplish this in draw.io? I found "divider" elements that can create rows, but nothing comparable to create vertical splits (columns).

I also tried containers that looked similar to above diagram, but the text in the columns doesn't react to the divider's position, nor does it appear to allow manual dragging to correct this. This means that any custom text will ruin the layout.

The answer to the following question [How do I add columns and rows in a draw.io table?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54754/how-do-i-add-columns-and-rows-in-a-draw-io-table) didn't help me. Only a few of the template object show a "table section" in the format panel, and only after double clicking the table followed by single click. Then - using said menu - one has to pry apart these overly complex, pre-styled containers, hoping to arrive at something simple.

Is there a bottom-up approach to what I want, or maybe a suitable container I missed?

Answer (score 5):

You are right, there seems to be no simple tables like we are used to from a spreadsheet but I searched for a table in the search bar.

Added a screenshot that might help:

[image: table search in draw.io]

Answer (score -5):

nope it is not possible to have a table in draw.io that has more than 3 items.

Comment: Having a reference for the claim would definitely make this a stronger answer, as has been pointed out.